# How secure is this Rock Paper Scissors smart contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, privacy

This contract has been out for a while (it's not mine). I wonder how secure it is. I understand encrypting & revealing process there, but what strikes me more is: When player1 calls method `play` with arguments `string choice, string randStr`, the fact that he called this method with those arguments is visible to all nodes on network, isn't it? Therefore player2 can search in blockchain transactions player1's call of `play` method and see `choice`? 
As far as I know transaction data isn't private.

Contract URL: https://github.com/SCBuergel/ethereum-rps/blob/master/rps-advanced.sol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, knowing the ABI/code of the contract you can see which function is being executed and with which parameters in a specific transaction.

Comment: Thanks. Any suggestions how to make such contract more secure?

Comment: My suggestion would be:  
1.- Player1 hashes the choice with a random seed in local and sends the result to the contract.  
2.- Player2 do the same.
3.- After both players have submitted their choice hashed, they have a period of time in which they have to send the choice and seeds used.  
4a.- After that time, the contract recalculates the hash to make sure none of them is lying and declares a winner.  
4b.- If one of the players doesn't submit the data, he loses.

(*) Player 2 could do steps 2 and 3 in the same transaction, so only player1 has to do it or player2 wins.

Comment: (**) Steps 3 and 4a could be executed in the same transaction from player1. 4b will be only executed by player2 after x amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

To your question, YES the moves that sent raw to blockchain can be seen by anybody and cheated though.

I proposed an interesting solution that eliminates these risks in this [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/87196/rock-paper-scissors-and-secrether-io).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think about the real estate market for this to go with your heart is the best way to make your life easier to get you the way you need to be able to make it happen and your family will be sure that you can find a way to make it happen

Comment: Your response is irrelevant. Please refrain from spamming.